# dyld: Library not loaded (image not found) but it's there

Tags: c++, qt, macos, deployment

I got this error when trying to launch my Qt-application (which was deployed with macdeployqt) on another Mac.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: kqoauth.framework/Versions/0/kqoauth
Referenced from: /MyProject.app/Contents/MacOS/MyProject
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap
```

I checked the .app-bundle and copied the kqoauth.framework to a few different locations (Frameworks-folder, next to the executable file, Resources-folder) but the error remained.
This is my project-tree:

[image]

I also tried otool -L on it and everything seems to be fine. (the entry for kqoauth.framework looked the same as those for the qt-libraries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that `otool -L` was showing relative paths for both Qt and for kqoauth, my guess is they are probably all starting at root `/` and you didn't see the qt loading failing, because they're installed on your system.

Regardless, I suggest following this tutorial to correctly inform the binary where all the dylibs are: [Qt Deploying on Mac OS X](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html). 
Here's the man for [install_name_tool](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/install_name_tool.1.html), which is used in that tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by changing the following settings

Go to **Project Setting Your_Target->General->Embedded Binaries-> Click on + button** and add your library here